# How to inline Heading and NavLinks using React and CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

trying to make a website's frontend here is my simple React code for Header

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import './Header.css';


function Header() {
  return (
    <nav>
      <Fragment>
      <h1>
        Your NAME
      </h1>
      </Fragment>
      
      <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/">
        Home
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/cart">
        Cart
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/Login">
        Login
      </NavLink>

    </nav>
  );
}
export default Header;
```

And here is my CSS Sheet :-

```
   div {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline block;
    }
    
    nav{
    
    text-align: top right;
    display: inline block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #41a3ee;
   
}
```

The Problem i am facing is i am unable to align them in single line don't why.
your help with greatly be appreciated.
THANKS!!!

Comment: I think there is another issue in your app, it would be better you add an ss of your output, there is nothing wrong with your css

Answer (score 0):

You should use flexbox. See the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

You should do like this:

```
nav {
  text-align: top right;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #41a3ee; 
}
```